# Firebase user creation is not working anymore

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I've been using the following code snippet in order to create a new user in Firebase/SimpleLogin for months:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + user.id);
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() === null) {
        // User not found! Create new user
        ref.parent().update(meupontoFire.createNewUser(user.id), function(error) {
            // Nothing happens now...
```

But that code isn't working anymore! I noticed it yesterday. It seems like the update call is not working (the data is not being stored). Does anyone know why? What has changed?

Comment: Does meupontoFire.createNewUser(user.id) return an array by chance?

.update() should always be called with an Object, and we'll update each child defined in the Object with the new value provided.  Passing it an array used to sort of work, but due to a recent change, this behavior was accidentally broken, and now update() *must* be called with an Object.

If that's the case, the easy "fix" is to return an Object with numeric keys instead "var obj = { }; obj[0] = ...; obj[1] = ...;" or whatever.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer No, it does not return an array. It always returns an Object.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the Object I pass and what is being updated:

```
ref.update(meupontoFire.createNewUser(), function(error) {
```

Now, instead of updating the reference's parent, I am updating the reference itself.